# Changing text selection color in visual mode in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I use black background and white text. The problem is, when I want to select some text in visual mode, the selected text is NOT visible at all, as both of them are white. I do not want to switch to light backgrounds. How can I change just the text selection color to something else, so that selected text is visible?

[image]

Comment: `set background=dark`? Should be set by your colorscheme.

Comment: @FDinoff I think you are spot on. It was set to light. Can you put your comment as an answer. I'll accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the colorscheme is supposed to be a dark colorscheme. It should automatically have

```
set background=dark
```

inside of it. If it doesn't you can add it after the colorscheme is loaded. If `background` is set to dark vim will try to use colors that look good on a dark background.

Take a look at `:help 'background'`